# How to change the output of a log file using sed

Tags: linux, logging, sed, output

I have the following output of a log file

```
/var/www/user/data/www/domain.com/wp-config.php
/var/www/anotheruser/data/www/otherdomain.com/wp-config.php
```

I am trying to get output like this:

```
domain.com
otherdomain.com
```

I only figured how to remove `/wp-config.php`, but i don't know how to remove everything till `domain.com`.

The problem is that they all are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's|.*/([^/]*)/.*|\1|' file
```

Comment: depending of sed version it could take from the second to 6th value between / / due to last .* ?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
awk -F'/' 'NF{print $(NF-1)}' log
```

Comment: +1 for this interresting approach, which will work fine if indeed it's always "/wp-config.php" (or /whatever-without-further-slashed) at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed --posix "s#^.*/\([^/]\{1,\}\)/[^/]*$#\1#"
```

If there is more info (sub folder) after the domain name, pattern need to work from the start and not from the end like this (taking the 6th pattern between / /) .

Answer (score 0):

A very short `awk`

```
awk -F/ '$0=$(NF-1)' file
domain.com
otherdomain.com
```